# mod_rewrite rule to capture query parameters if present

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/(v[0-9]+)/(resource)/?$ /$1/file.php?resource=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/(v[0-9]+)/(resource)/([A-z0-9_]+)/?$ /$1/file.php?resource=$2&resource_id=$3 [NC,L]
```

This rewrites URLs like

```
/v1/resource/ to /v1/file.php?resource=resource
```

and

```
/v1/resource/resource_id to /v1/file.php?resource=resource&resource_id=resource_id
```

How can I write a rule that takes in consideration a query parameter in the “beautified” URL? E.g.

```
/v1/resource/?filter=filter_val to /v1/file.php?resource=resource&filter=filter_val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add "QSA" (="query string append") in the square brackets:

```
RewriteRule ^/(v[0-9]+)/(resource)/?$ /$1/file.php?resource=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

You may read this for further reference:
[Apache Doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: Whoa! That was easy! Thanks a lot!